# Reflection necessary to avoid NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: reflection, java

I'm programming against a library.

In version 1, that library had a method getFoo() which returned a Map

In version 2, that method getFoo() now returns a Set

I thought that my code could happily:

```
  Object foo = library.getFoo();
```

and work whether the library returns a Map or a Set.

However, when I compile my code against version 1 of the library, but run it against version 2, I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getFoo()Ljava/util/Map;

At least that is what happens with

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

I've now addressed this by using reflection, but I hadn't thought that would be necessary.

So my question is, is it ever safe to do Object foo = library.getFoo(), and if the answer to that is "sometimes" or "it depends", then why wasn't it ok in this case?

Comment: Writig a code with a different library and running the same code with a different library is itself a problem. I believe you should try to rectify the lib mismatch instead of handling it in code.

Comment: That is a VERY tough question... You'd think it would be perfectly fine. Now I know both `Map` and `Set` are interfaces, however not much about them. Checking the javadocs for [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) shows that `Set` extends `Collection` while `Map` doesn't extend anything. Does this have something to do with it? It also could be that `Map` has modifier of `<X, Y>` while `Set` only has `<X>`.

Comment: In fact, that second idea I think is the issue there. Since it returns a `Set` of `<Something>`, but a map gives two `<Of, These>`, they aren't compatible. Maybe they just gave that default error message instead of making a new one for this case.

Comment: It seems like your question is not wholly related to your situation. The question of using an object as a base class is solved by simply looking at the inheritance tree of both objects. Your issue was not about Object but a about Java not being able to find getFoo()Ljava/util/Map during runtime. This has nothing to do with the variable you end up storing the result in.

Answer (score 1):

When you compiled the code using version 1, your the class byte code has entry for this method with return type as Map. At runtime the class is loaded, class definition has getFoo() with return type as Map, and hence JVM is not able to locate the method since you are running it against a different version of the class which has method with different return type(Set in your case).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is perfectly valid.

Option 1: Use reflection in your code to dynamically do the right thing with whatever version of the library you find at runtime.

Option 2: If you want your code to run with either version of the library, you will need both versions available at compile time. You will need some code to decide which version is being used at runtime and conditionally execute your code that was compiled to call the proper version of the library. If the library author was unkind, you may end up having to work around class name conflicts.

Reflection (option 1) is likely to be the easiest and most flexible approach.

You probably want to create a wrapper API that abstracts the differences between the two versions of the library, so this ickiness doesn't leak into the rest of your application.